# C on LINUX - Multiple child proces exec unusual number of times

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create n = 10 child processes and make its execute a peace of code ..
However it creates 14 child processes indifferent of n. 
Why is that?

This is the sample code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("It worked! ");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int n = 10;
     pid_t pid;

     int status = 0;
     int fd2[2];
     int i = 0;

     while (i < n)
     {
         /*create the pipe */
         if (pipe(fd2) == -1)
         {
             fprintf(stderr, "Problem at pipe: %s\n", strerror(errno));
             exit(1);
         }

         /*create fork*/
         pid = fork();

         if (pid == -1)
         {
             fprintf(stderr, "Problem at fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
             exit(1);
         }
         else if (pid == 0)  /*in child*/
         {
             close(fd2[0]); 
             close(1);
             dup2(fd2[1], 1);
             close(fd2[1]);

             execl("sample.bin", "sample.bin", NULL);

             fprintf(stderr, "Problem at exec: %s", strerror(errno));
             exit(1);
         }

         /* in parent */
         close(fd2[1]);
         char line[255];

         if (n = read(fd2[0], line, 254))
         {
             printf("%d The message is: %s\n", i, line);
         }

         close(fd2[0]);

         wait(&status);
         i++;        
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: A few (unrelated) things: You don't need the `close(1)` in the child, it will be done automatically by `dup2` (read [the `dup2` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html)). Secondly you don't terminate the data you read from the child process.

Comment: As for your problem, how do you count the number of child processes? What is your actual and expected output when running?

Comment: You have a lot of code there that seems not directly related to the the forking. Do the problems go way when removing this code? Is this the *minimal* amount of code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Adding to Some programmer dudes comment: Have you consulted your [rubber duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I expect to create n child processes. The output is showing, even for n = 2,  14 child processes created and it show 14 times the message "It worked!"

Comment: @HermannDöppes the article you showed me is great! :)

Comment: @user3676857 I am not sure how are you testing the program. As I just compiled the code and adjusted the n.  I get "It worked!" msg n number of times

Comment: I wrote again the program by starting minimalistic: I created multiple child processes and put an exec in the child process without pipe; it worked, output the message n times;

Then I put the pipe just like in this program and it worked.

Comment: I've found the problem. The code that I've wrote here has less details then the original code. In the original code the problem was this:
 
 if (n = read(fd2[0], line, 254))  ;  there was no condition there

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice !

Comment: I'm always glad to help people who are willing to do their homework. You needed only a few little hints and were able to do it yourself, that's not as common as one might think. If you keep up the pace, we all look forward to the questions and answers in your future.

Comment: For posterity it would be great if you “fixed” the code in the question (i.e., making it not-work again) and posted the solution you found as an answer.

Comment: Ok.. I will do that

Answer (score 2):

I corrected the code, now the output is what I've expected. And of course another problem was that I used at read the same variable n.

I modified from this:

```
if (n = read(fd2[0], line, 254))
{
   printf("%d The message is: %s\n", i, line);
}
```

To this:

```
int m;
while((m = read(fd2[0], line, 254) > 0)
{
   printf("%d The message is: %s\n", i, line);
}
```

Comment: This is a good lesson in why meaningful names help ... if your original `n` had been `MaxChildProcesses`, you would have been much less likely to accidentally reuse it.